# Bash trap not killing children, causes unexpected ctrl-c behavior

Tags: linux, bash, inotify

**edit**

For future readers. The root of this problem really came down to running the function in an interactive shell vs. putting it in a separate script.

Also, there are many things that could be improved in the code I originally posted. Please see comments for things that could/should have been done better.

**/edit**

I have a bash function intended to rerun a process in the background when files in a directory change (think like Grunt, but for general purposes). The script functions as desired while running:

- The subprocess is correctly started (including any children)
- On file change, the sub is killed (including children) and started again

However, on exit (ctrl-c) none of the processes are killed. Additionally, pressing ctrl-c a second time will kill the current terminal session. I'm assuming this is a problem with my trap, but have been unable to identify a reason for the issue.

Here is the code of rerun.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# rerun.sh

_kill_children() {
    isTop=$1
    curPid=$2
        # Get pids of children
    children=`ps -o pid --no-headers --ppid ${curPid}`
    for child in $children
    do
            # Call this function to get grandchildren as well
            _kill_children 0 $child
    done
    # Parent calls this with 1, all other with 0 so only children are killed
    if [[ $isTop -eq 0 ]]; then
            kill -9 $curPid 2> /dev/null
    fi
}

rerun() {
    trap " _kill_children 1 $$; exit 0" SIGINT SIGTERM
    FORMAT=$(echo -e "\033[1;33m%w%f\033[0m written")
    #Command that should be repeatedly run is passed as args
    args=$@
    $args &

    #When a file changes in the directory, rerun the process
    while inotifywait -qre close_write --format "$FORMAT" .
    do
        #Kill current bg proc and it's children
        _kill_children 1 $$
        $args & #Rerun the proc
    done
}

#This is sourced in my bash profile so I can run it any time
```

To test this, create a pair of executable files parent.sh and child.sh as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#parent.sh
./child.sh

#!/bin/bash
#child.sh
sleep 86400
```

Then source the rerun.sh file and run `rerun ./parent.sh`. In another terminal window I `watch "ps -ef | grep pts/4"` to see all processes for the rerun (in this example on pts/4). Touching a file in the directory triggers a restart of parent.sh and children. [ctrl-c] exits, but leaves the pids running. [ctrl-c] again kills bash and all other processes on pts/4.

Desired behavior: on [ctrl-c], kill children and exit to shell normally. Help?

--
Code sources:

Inotify idea from: https://exyr.org/2011/inotify-run/

Kill children from: http://riccomini.name/posts/linux/2012-09-25-kill-subprocesses-linux-bash/

Comment: There's a lot in here that's nasty. `args=$@`, for instance, is wrong on its face -- `$@` is an array, `args` is a scalar. You **can't** reliably put an array in a scalar, and when you run `$args` later, you hit all the pitfalls in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

Comment: Also, the quoting. So, **so** very wrong.

Comment: (Also, don't use SIGKILL unless you've already given something a SIGTERM and waited long enough to let it try to clean up gracefully).

Comment: If you want implicit tracking of grandchildren &c., consider using a lockfile and `fuser -k` instead of trying to parse `ps`.

Comment: Also, `echo -e` is evil -- as in, bash violates the POSIX specification (not extends, violates -- a POSIX-compliant echo would print `-e` on its output when passed `-e` on its command line) by including it; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html. `printf` is the best-practices alternative.

Comment: Oh man. Glad I posted... looks like I've got a few things to learn here. @CharlesDuffy thanks for the links, I'll read up.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You mention the quoting being wrong... can you clarify what quoting you're referring to? Do you mean the trap? If so... how would I write it better?

Comment: Also, avoid all-caps names for your own variables -- these are reserved for built-in and system variables. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: With respect to the quoting, try running your original code through http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: ...or see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for a longer introduction.

Comment: ...and if you want to know the right way to use arrays in bash, see BashFAQ #5: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a good practice to follow in the first place. Track your children explicitly:

```
children=( )
foo & children+=( "$!" )
```

...then, you can kill or wait for them explicitly, referring to `"${children[@]}"` for the list. If you want to get grandchildren as well, this is a good user for `fuser -k` and a lockfile:

```
lockfile_name="$(mktemp /tmp/lockfile.XXXXXX)" # change appropriately
trap 'rm -f "$lockfile_name"' 0

exec 3>"$lockfile_name" # open lockfile on FD 3
kill_children() {
    # close our own handle on the lockfile
    exec 3>&-

    # kill everything that still has it open (our children and their children)
    fuser -k "$lockfile_name" >/dev/null

    # ...then open it again.
    exec 3>"$lockfile_name"
}

rerun() {
    trap 'kill_children; exit 0' SIGINT SIGTERM
    printf -v format '%b' "\033[1;33m%w%f\033[0m written"

    "$@" &

    #When a file changes in the directory, rerun the process
    while inotifywait -qre close_write --format "$format" .; do
        kill_children
        "$@" &
    done
}
```

Comment: This solution also doesn't work. Try running this with the steps I suggested (i.e. source the file, call `rerun ./parent.sh`). When you hit [ctrl-c] to exit, the processes aren't killed and pressing [ctrl-c] again kills the terminal.

Comment: An interactive shell is a whole different pile of worms. Is that really the use case you're writing this for? I created a script called `rerun` that simply calls `rerun "$@"`, as defined precisely above, and it Does The Right Thing when invoked as `./rerun sh -c 'while sleep 1; do ((++i)); echo "$i"; done'`.

Comment: Short form: Don't define `rerun` as a function; put it in its own script. No reason for dealing with the headaches of interactive job control.